# PlayStore: Cannot see Open testing build while there is an Internal Test build

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

about a week back, I uploaded an Internal test build and release it to my testers from Play Store.
Now, I uploaded a new build under Open Testing. It shows me that it's rolled out.
But when I download it from the link provided, I can only see the internal test build while downloading.
Can anyone help? How to disable the internal test build or how will the open test build show up?

Comment: Have you added yourself to the open testing track and accepted the invite?

Comment: Do I need to add myself? because I can only see options to either open it for unlimited users or limit it to minimum of 1000 users?

Comment: However I added myself to Internal testers list but does it really affect the open tests?